# aws s3 mv command is not deleting the folder structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

aws s3 mv s3://test/paltest/ . --recursive

All files within the paltest is been moved but paltest is not deleted. But i am able to remove paltest using aws s3 rm s3://test/paltest/

Answer (score 0):

S3 is not a file system, it doesn't have folders, but it shows them to make it easier for humans to understand.

Once the key (aka folder) /paltest/ has no contents S3 will stop displaying it. Is versioning turned on for the bucket?